# Keras model errors

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm new to machine learning and have been stuck with this error for awhile now:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "model1.py", line 77, in 
> model.fit(train_generator,
> File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
> return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1098, in fit
> tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
> File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 780, in **call**
> result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
> File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 840, in _call
> return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
> File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2829, in **call**
> return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
> File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1843, in _filtered_call
> return self._call_flat(
> File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1923, in _call_flat
> return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
> File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 545, in call
> outputs = execute.execute(
> File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 59, in quick_execute
> tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError:  No algorithm worked!
> [[node sequential/conv2d/Conv2D (defined at model1.py:77) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_806]

I'm using CUDA 10.1/Cudnn 8.05, which works fine for the other convolution projects I've tried.  Just switching to the basic VGG16 model here lets me run the program without any accuracy gains, so I'm not sure if the issue is with my GPU's libraries, a mistake in the tensor dimensions, or a failure to initialize something.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
# Helper libraries
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras import layers

batch_size=10
train_dir="C:/draw/imagenet-object-localization-challenge/ILSVRC/Data/CLS-LOC/train"     
validation_dir="C:/draw/imagenet-object-localization-challenge/ILSVRC/Data/CLS-LOC/val"


train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      rescale=1./255,
      rotation_range=40,
      width_shift_range=0.2,
      height_shift_range=0.2,
      shear_range=0.2,
      zoom_range=0.2,
      horizontal_flip=True,
      validation_split=0.2,
      fill_mode='nearest')


train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_dir,
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical')
validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_dir,
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical')

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(224, 224, 1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64))
model.add(layers.Dense(1000, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
                         loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), 
                         metrics=['accuracy'])
num_epochs=20
steps_per_epoch=10000
val_steps=10
model.fit(train_generator,
          epochs=num_epochs,
          steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch,
          validation_data=validation_generator, 
          validation_steps=val_steps)
```

Thanks in advance for any advice provided in how to fix this error.

Comment: please add error msg in text format.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that in flow_from_directory you need to specify the parameter subset. For the train_generator specify the subset as subset='training'. In the validation_generator specify it as subset='validation'.

Comment: Thanks, I missed this error.  The "algorithm not found" problem seems to be something different though.

Comment: try removing  from_logits=True in model.compile loss

Comment: This fixed solved it, along with two others: Adding 'color_mode=grayscale' and a specialized gpu memory growth code block that varies based on the installed cuda/cudnn versions.